# Received memory warning and crashing when trying to fetch heavy image from photos

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6

Trying to fetch the images of approximately 5-8 mb from photos it gives "Received memory warning" message first then crash with the message in console "Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died".
What type of error this is and what is the solution for it? Please guide.
Update:
One more thing want to add using MTImageViewController to crop the image.

Getting crashed in this method:

```
- (UIImage *)getImageFromCurrenView  {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

 CGRect newSize = CGRectMake(transparentView.frame.origin.x, transparentView.frame.origin.y,transparentView.frame.size.width, transparentView.frame.size.height);
CGImageRef tmp = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], newSize);
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:tmp];
CGImageRelease(tmp);

return newImage;
}
```

Using MTImageViewController to crop the image, this method is in MTImageViewController.m

Comment: That code looks like it takes a screenshot.  What's that got to do with loading an image from *photos*?